# 2019 iPad 10.2" (128gb) vs iPad mini 5 (64gb) - which one to choose?

Tags: ipad

I have an iPhone 7 and MacBook Air. Now planning to buy an iPad. But stuck between these 2 models. I will buy it mainly for Games, YouTube and Reading. I want to know the Pros and Cons from 1st-hand user experience. Please help.

Comment: One has bigger screen and more memory. Do you want that, or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare all the model's specs from this page: https://www.apple.com/fr/ipad/compare/

It depends mostly on your budget, but I'd take the 2019 iPad for the wider screen which is better if you play and read a lot. You can connect an Xbox controller on both iPad, and they have the same battery life.